# Tween js in Three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, tweenjs

I would like to ask some questions about tween js in three js. Here is the coding where  the particles are formed as the image below:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTzl1.jpg)

```
var scene;
var renderer;
var container
var stats;
var sphere

var clock;
var deltaTime;
var mouse;
var raycaster;


init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    clock = new THREE.Clock(true);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 120;


    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 2, 2, 1 ).normalize();
    scene.add(light);


    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    var geometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );

    var geometry3 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry3, material3 );

    var geometry4 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,transparent: true, opacity: 0.5} );
    sphere4 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry4, material4 );

    var geometry5 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    sphere5 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry5, material5 );

    var geometry6 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material6 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere6 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry6, material6 );

    var geometry7 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material7 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,transparent: true, opacity: 0.5} );
    sphere7 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry7, material7 );


    var geometry8 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material8 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere8 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry8, material8 );


    var geometry9 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material9 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere9 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry9, material9 );


    var geometryo = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1o = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,transparent: true, opacity: 0.5} );
    sphereo = new THREE.Mesh( geometryo, material1o );

    var geometryt = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1t = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    spheret = new THREE.Mesh( geometryt, material1t );

    var geometryth = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1th = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphereth = new THREE.Mesh( geometryth, material1th );

    var geometryf = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1f = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    spheref = new THREE.Mesh( geometryf, material1f );

    var geometryfi = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1fi = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    spherefi = new THREE.Mesh( geometryfi, material1fi );

    var geometrys = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1s = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    spheres = new THREE.Mesh( geometrys, material1s);

    var geometryse = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1se = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    spherese = new THREE.Mesh( geometryse, material1se );

    var geometrye = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1e = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    spheree = new THREE.Mesh( geometrye, material1e );

    var geometryn= new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1n = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    spheren = new THREE.Mesh( geometryn, material1n );

    var geometryten = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1ten = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphereten = new THREE.Mesh( geometryten, material1ten );

    var geometryel = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1el = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphereel = new THREE.Mesh( geometryel, material1el);

    var geometrytw = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1tw = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    spheretw = new THREE.Mesh( geometrytw, material1tw);

    var geometrytt = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1tt = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    spherett = new THREE.Mesh( geometrytt, material1tt);

    var geometryft = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1ft = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    sphereft = new THREE.Mesh( geometryft, material1ft);

    var geometryfit = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material1fit = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    spherefit = new THREE.Mesh( geometryfit, material1fit);

    var geometry16 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material116 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere16 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry16, material116);

    var geometry17= new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material17 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere17 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry17, material17);

    var geometry18 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material118 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere18 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry18, material118);

    var geometry19 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material119 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere19 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry19, material119);

    var geometry20 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material120 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    sphere20 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry20, material120);

    var geometry21 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material21 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere21 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry21, material21);

    var geometry22 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material22 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere22 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry22, material22);

    var geometry23 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material23 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere23 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry23, material23);

    var geometry24 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material24 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    sphere24 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry24, material24);

    var geometry25 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material25 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere25 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry25, material25);

    var geometry26 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material26 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere26 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry26, material26);

     var geometry27 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material27 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere27 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry27, material27);

    var geometry28 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material28 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere28 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry28, material28);

    var geometry29 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material29 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere29 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry29, material29);

    var geometry30 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material30 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere30 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry30, material30);

    var geometry31 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material31 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere31 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry31, material31);

    var geometry32 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material32 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere32 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry32, material32);

    var geometry33 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material33 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere33 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry33, material33);

    var geometry34 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material34 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere34 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry34, material34);

    var geometry35 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material35 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere35 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry35, material35);

    var geometry36 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material36 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere36 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry36, material36);

    var geometry37 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material37 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    sphere37 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry37, material37);

    var geometry38 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material38= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere38 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry38, material38);

    var geometry39 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material39= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    sphere39 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry39, material39);

    var geometry40 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material40= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff4ba0,} );
    sphere40 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry40, material40);

    var geometry41 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material41= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff89c1,} );
    sphere41 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry41, material41);

    var geometry42 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3, 10, 10 );
    var material42= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe62fac,} );
    sphere42 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry42, material42);


    sphere.position.z = -1;
    sphere.position.x = -5
    sphere.position.y = 20
    scene.add( sphere );

    sphere2.position.z = -50;
    sphere2.position.x = -18
    sphere2.position.y = 35
    scene.add( sphere2 );

    sphere3.position.z = -1;
    sphere3.position.x = -20
    sphere3.position.y = 30
    scene.add( sphere3 );

    sphere4.position.z = -1;
    sphere4.position.x = -27
    sphere4.position.y = 30
    scene.add( sphere4 );

    sphere5.position.z = -1;
    sphere5.position.x = -35
    sphere5.position.y = 25
    scene.add( sphere5 );

    sphere6.position.z = -1;
    sphere6.position.x = -40
    sphere6.position.y = 15
    scene.add( sphere6 );

    sphere7.position.z = -1;
    sphere7.position.x = -35
    sphere7.position.y = 5
    scene.add( sphere7 );

    sphere8.position.z = -1;
    sphere8.position.x = -30
    sphere8.position.y =-3
    scene.add( sphere8);

    sphere9.position.z = -1;
    sphere9.position.x = -25
    sphere9.position.y =-11
    scene.add( sphere9);

    sphereo.position.z = -1;
    sphereo.position.x = -18
    sphereo.position.y =-20
    scene.add( sphereo);

    spheret.position.z = -1;
    spheret.position.x = -12
    spheret.position.y =-25
    scene.add( spheret);

    sphereth.position.z = -1;
    sphereth.position.x = -4
    sphereth.position.y =-31
    scene.add( sphereth);

    spheref.position.z = -1;
    spheref.position.x = 5
    spheref.position.y =-25
    scene.add( spheref);

    spherefi.position.z = -1;
    spherefi.position.x = 13
    spherefi.position.y =-19
    scene.add( spherefi);

    spheres.position.z = -1;
    spheres.position.x = 19
    spheres.position.y =-14
    scene.add( spheres);

    spherese.position.z = -1;
    spherese.position.x = 25
    spherese.position.y =-5
    scene.add( spherese);

    spheree.position.z = -1;
    spheree.position.x = 30
    spheree.position.y =4
    scene.add( spheree);

    spheren.position.z = -1;
    spheren.position.x = 35
    spheren.position.y =12
    scene.add( spheren);

    sphereten.position.z = -1;
    sphereten.position.x = 20
    sphereten.position.y =23
    scene.add( sphereten);

    sphereel.position.z = -1;
    sphereel.position.x = 31
    sphereel.position.y =23
    scene.add( sphereel);

    spheretw.position.z = -1;
    spheretw.position.x = 25
    spheretw.position.y =30
    scene.add( spheretw);

    spherett.position.z = -1;
    spherett.position.x = 15
    spherett.position.y =30
    scene.add( spherett);

    sphereft.position.z = -1;
    sphereft.position.x = 5
    sphereft.position.y =26
    scene.add( sphereft);

    spherefit.position.z = -1;
    spherefit.position.x = 15
    spherefit.position.y = 17
    scene.add( spherefit);

    sphere16.position.z = -1;
    sphere16.position.x = 25
    sphere16.position.y = 15
    scene.add( sphere16);

    sphere17.position.z = -1;
    sphere17.position.x = 20
    sphere17.position.y = 5
    scene.add( sphere17);

    sphere18.position.z = -1;
    sphere18.position.x = 5
    sphere18.position.y = 15
    scene.add( sphere18);

    sphere19.position.z = -1;
    sphere19.position.x = -5
    sphere19.position.y = 11
    scene.add( sphere19);

    sphere20.position.z = -1;
    sphere20.position.x = -12
    sphere20.position.y = 15
    scene.add( sphere20);

    sphere21.position.z = -1;
    sphere21.position.x = -20
    sphere21.position.y = 20
    scene.add( sphere21);

    sphere22.position.z = -1;
    sphere22.position.x = -28
    sphere22.position.y = 23
    scene.add( sphere22);

    sphere23.position.z = -1;
    sphere23.position.x = -30
    sphere23.position.y = 15
    scene.add( sphere23);

    sphere24.position.z = -1;
    sphere24.position.x = -27
    sphere24.position.y = 7
    scene.add( sphere24);

    sphere25.position.z = -1;
    sphere25.position.x = -21
    sphere25.position.y = -2
    scene.add( sphere25);

    sphere26.position.z = -1;
    sphere26.position.x = -16
    sphere26.position.y = -10
    scene.add( sphere26);

    sphere27.position.z = -1;
    sphere27.position.x = -10
    sphere27.position.y = -17
    scene.add( sphere27);

    sphere28.position.z = -1;
    sphere28.position.x = -4
    sphere28.position.y = -23
    scene.add( sphere28);

    sphere29.position.z = -1;
    sphere29.position.x = 5
    sphere29.position.y = -15
    scene.add( sphere29);

    sphere30.position.z = -1;
    sphere30.position.x = 10
    sphere30.position.y = -9
    scene.add( sphere30);

    sphere32.position.z = -1;
    sphere32.position.x = 15
    sphere32.position.y = -1
    scene.add( sphere32);

    sphere31.position.z = -1;
    sphere31.position.x = 10
    sphere31.position.y = 10
    scene.add( sphere31);

    sphere33.position.z = -1;
    sphere33.position.x = 5
    sphere33.position.y = 1
    scene.add( sphere33);

    sphere34.position.z = -1;
    sphere34.position.x = 5
    sphere34.position.y = 1
    scene.add( sphere34);

    sphere35.position.z = -1;
    sphere35.position.x = 5
    sphere35.position.y = 1
    scene.add( sphere35);

    sphere36.position.z = -1;
    sphere36.position.x = 5
    sphere36.position.y = 1
    scene.add( sphere36);

    sphere37.position.z = -1;
    sphere37.position.x = 5
    sphere37.position.y = 1
    scene.add( sphere37);

    sphere38.position.z = -1;
    sphere38.position.x = -5
    sphere38.position.y = 1
    scene.add( sphere38);

    sphere39.position.z = -1;
    sphere39.position.x = -18
    sphere39.position.y = 5
    scene.add( sphere39);

    sphere40.position.z = -1;
    sphere40.position.x = -13
    sphere40.position.y = -1
    scene.add( sphere40);

    sphere41.position.z = -1;
    sphere41.position.x = -3
    sphere41.position.y = -10
    scene.add( sphere41);

    sphere42.position.z = -1;
    sphere42.position.x = -20
    sphere42.position.y = 13
    scene.add( sphere42);


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown , false); 
    document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseClick, false );
    render();

}
```

From here, this is the tween coding where the particles will move around when the particles is clicked. But, it seem that my particles are failed to tween.Can I know what have I missed in the coding and what is the problem that I faced?

```
function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    render();
}


function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                event.clientX = event.touches[0].clientX;
                event.clientY = event.touches[0].clientY;
                onDocumentMouseDown( event );


    }   

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
                console.log(mouse.x + ' ' + mouse.y);
                raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                    new TWEEN.Tween( intersects[ 0 ].object.position ).to( {
                        x: Math.random() * 20,
                        y: Math.random() * 20,
                        z: Math.random() * 800 - 400 }, 2000 )
                    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.Out).start();

}

}


function onDocumentMouseClick(){
    animatemove();
    console.log ('you clicked me');
    }


function animatemove(){

    sphere.position.x += 10;
    sphere.position.y += 5;

    sphere2.position.x += 90;
    sphere2.position.y += 15;

    sphere3.position.x += -50;
    sphere3.position.y += 5;

    sphere4.position.x += -20;
    sphere4.position.y += 5;

    sphere5.position.x += -10;
    sphere5.position.y += 5;
    console.log ('you clicked me ');
    render();
//  requestAnimationFrame( animatemove );
    }


function animate() {
    deltaTime = clock.getDelta();

    sphere.rotation.x += 1 * deltaTime;
    sphere.rotation.y += 2 * deltaTime;
//  sphere.position.x += 3* deltaTime;

    sphere2.rotation.x += 1 * deltaTime;
    sphere2.rotation.y += 2 * deltaTime;

    sphere3.rotation.x += 1 * deltaTime;
    sphere3.rotation.y += 2 * deltaTime;

    sphere3.rotation.x += 1 * deltaTime;
    sphere3.rotation.y += 2 * deltaTime;

    sphere4.rotation.x += 1 * deltaTime;
    sphere4.rotation.y += 2 * deltaTime;

    sphere5.rotation.x += 1 * deltaTime;
    sphere5.rotation.y += 2 * deltaTime;

    sphere6.rotation.x += 1 * deltaTime;
    sphere6.rotation.y += 2 * deltaTime;

    sphere7.rotation.x += 1 * deltaTime;
    sphere7.rotation.y += 2 * deltaTime;

    sphere8.rotation.x += 1 * deltaTime;
    sphere8.rotation.y += 2 * deltaTime;

    sphere9.rotation.x += 1 * deltaTime;
    sphere9.rotation.y += 2 * deltaTime;

    render();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

function render() {

    TWEEN.update();

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: is `intersects.length > 0` ever true?

Comment: Can I know what is effect when I change the number?

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand your post?

Comment: @yukikoying do you have any error messages in your browser console?

Comment: @prisoner849 no, there is no error message in the browser console

Comment: @yukikoying I've tried to make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/8yL4wc6k/) example with your code from here and I've got error messages that variables `raycaster` and `mouse` were undefined.

Comment: @prisoner849 the tween is working! thanks!:D Erm if I want to set the particles to tween to a certain place. Is that mean i need to adjust the number? Or is it okie if i apply example:sphere.math random = 100?

Comment: @yukikoying well... if you want your points to be random, then you can define your heart with the function an then check if a random point is inside of your "heart"

Comment: @prisoner849 if i want to make the particles in the certain position, then i need to remove the 'random' word?

Comment: @yukikoying in your code you already have particles at certain positions.

Comment: @prisoner849 okie i will try to work with the code again thanks for the suggestion:)

Comment: @prisoner849 Hello, would like to ask another question about retrieve data from mySQL by using Jquery.

Here is the code:
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#dots1").click(function(){  
   $("#Messagebox").show();
   $( "#Messagebox" ).load( "message.php", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );

}); 
}); 

 $("#dots1") is the variable that click and messagebox appear.
I woulid like to show the data on the message box. Is that the proper way to work on it?

Comment: @yukikoying with all respect, but it's better to create a new SO question with according tags )

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define start and end objects and add an "onUpdate" callback.

This should work:

```
let params = { 
     x:intersects[ 0 ].object.position.x,
     y:intersects[ 0 ].object.position.y,
     z:intersects[ 0 ].object.position.z
}

new TWEEN.Tween( params )
    .to( { x: Math.random() * 20,  y: Math.random() * 20, z: Math.random() * 800 - 400 }, 2000 )
    .onUpdate(()=>intersects[ 0 ].object.position.set(params.x, params.y, params.z))
    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.Out)
    .start();
```